# Using functor in lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, functor

I'm getting hung up on some syntax for working with functors and lambdas in C++.

I define functors as:

```
class paint : public OpCode {
public:
    using OpCode::OpCode;

    void operator()(std::int_fast32_t d) override {
        if (character_context->is_black()) {
            character_context->bitmap.add_blackline(character_context->m, character_context->n, d);
        }
        character_context->m += d;
        character_context->toggle_color();
    }

};

class get1byte : public Argument {
public:
    using Argument::Argument;

    int_fast32_t operator()() override {
        return file_context->read1();
    }
};
```

I can call these explicitly by doing, e.g.,

```
paint _paint (characterContext);
get1byte _1byte (fileContext);

_paint(_1byte());
```

(or this at least compiles).

But then I have

```
std::array<std::function<void()>, 256> opcodes;
opcodes[64] = [_paint, _1byte](){ _paint(_1byte()); };
```

which has the compiler complaining,

```
No matching function for call to object of type 'const get1byte'
```

How do I get this to work as expected? I'd prefer to avoid modifying the `OpCode` `operator()` signature to take `Argument` since in some instances I'd like to put a lambda in with a constant value in the argument to, e.g., `_paint`.

Comment: Objects captured in a lambda are `const` unless the lambda is marked as `mutable`.  Your `operator()`'s are not marked as `const`, so they can't be called on `const` objects. Also, note your lambda is capturing the objects *by value*, so it is operating on *copies* of them, is that what you really want? If not, capture the objects *by reference* instead.

Comment: You'll also have problems if the underlying objects disappear. If you're storing these opcodes for lookup later, then you need to make sure _paint and _1byte aren't destroyed before you use the lambdas.

Comment: Objects captured *by value* in a lambda are `const` unless the lambda is marked as `mutable`. https://godbolt.org/z/51dc5d

Comment: @RemyLebeau Do I mark the method `const` or the argument to it? I think I do want copies. The functors generally only have a single `shared_ptr` as their contents and I'm initializing them in the constructor. (which now that I think about it is potentially a problem). I suspect C++ people would look at my codebase and shake their heads and mutter, "Java programmer" at my code.

Comment: @DonHosek You would have to mark the `operator()` itself as `const`, eg: `void operator()(std::int_fast32_t d) const override` ... `int_fast32_t operator()() const override`, which means the base class `operator()` has to be `const` as well since you are using `override`.  If this is not an option, then use `mutable` on the lambda instead: `[_paint, _1byte]() mutable { _paint(_1byte()); };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Remy Lebeau's directions, I have managed to figure out what I needed to do: I had to add `const` to the declarations of my operator functions, e.g.,

```
int_fast32_t operator()() const override {
    return file_context->read1();
}
```

in an `Argument` implementation, with the abstract base class defining the method as

```
virtual std::int_fast32_t operator()() const = 0;
```

Then I was able to write my assignments as, e.g.,

```
opcodes[64] = [=](){ _paint(_1byte()); };
```

and all was well (or at least doesn't generate compiler errors—we'll see once I've finished updating my code). I've even managed to improve another piece of code using `std::generate` to have a lambda make a lambda:

```
std::generate_n(opcodes.begin(), 64, [&index, _paint](){ auto rv = [=](){_paint(index);  }; ++index; return rv; });
```

and with any luck, all will be well (although since I have a similar construction happening later in the fill, I'll likely refactor the lambda as a function).